# How can I restore corrupt .edb?

Tags: exchange

I have an exchange server with a .edb that is in a dirty shutdown state. I have 2 storage groups. The second storage group will not mount due to dirty shutdown. That database is on e: drive, the transaction logs are in C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Mailbox\Second Storage Group

I tried to run `eseutil /mh e:\exdb2` but I get an error saying that the file is locked.
What is the exact command I need to run to repair the .edb?

Answer (score 1):

Still eseutil like you told, but close exchange service if you can't get a lock on the file. (but do a copy of the DB before, as esutil is like a hack & slash of an axe)

> Restart the server. I know everyone is tired of hearing this advice
>   from Microsoft support people, but let's face it--it's a really good
>   way of clearing out random problems in an environment and getting you
>   back to a good state when you don't have time to find the root cause
>   before correcting the problem.
>
> 2.Make a copy of the database files(s) before you repair them. You'll probably skip doing this, but at least I told you. :)
>
> If you're not sure where your database files are, or what they are
>   called, you can find out in Exchange System Manager by accessing the
>   database properties. The Database page lists the paths and names.
>
> 3.Verify that you have sufficient disk space to do the repair. As a general rule of thumb, you should have the equivalent of 20% of the
>   database size. If you don't have that much free space on the drive
>   where the database files are, you can use command line switches to
>   redirect the temporary files created during repair to a different
>   drive.
>
> 4.Run Eseutil in /P (repair) mode.
>
> The easiest way to do this is to have both database files (.EDB and
>   .STM) in the same directory (which they usually are). If they're in
>   different places, you're going to have to point to the files on the
>   command line.
>
> Eseutil is found in the \exchsrvr\bin directory created when you
>   install Exchange on a server. You may want to add \exchsrvr\bin to
>   your system path for convenience.

[Repairing Exchange databases with ESEUTIL - when and how?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2004/06/18/159413.aspx)

Comment: -Be very careful on doing ANYTHING on EDB file. Using ESEUTIL /p is last action that is only run when you don't have updated backup to restore the database. Refer following article to fix dirty shutdown error: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2217-repairing-a-corrupt-or-dirty-exchange-database